# Summarise by week, even for empty rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to summarise the sum of sales.quantity by week, and to show the week number even if there are no sales.

I have setup a weeks table with 1-54 in there to use an outer join to force all week numbers to come through, but it isn't working. It misses out weeks where there have been no sales.

My query is:

```
SELECT Weeks.WeekNum, SUM(sales.quantity) AS sales
FROM Weeks LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     sales ON Weeks.WeekNum = DATEPART(week, sales.transDate)
WHERE (sales.transDate BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate)
GROUP BY Weeks.WeekNum
```

ANY help would be greatly received... it's probably something stupid that I've done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The where clause `WHERE (sales.transDate BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate)` will remove any weeks without sales.  You'll likely need to do a subquery to pull the transactions and then join that to your weeks table.

```
SELECT Weeks.WeekNum, SUM(sales.quantity) AS sales
FROM Weeks LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 (
    SELECT *
    FROM sales 
    WHERE (sales.transDate BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate)
 ) sales
    ON Weeks.WeekNum = DATEPART(week, sales.transDate)
GROUP BY Weeks.WeekNum
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this method versus a sub-select

```
SELECT Weeks.WeekNum, SUM(sales.quantity) AS sales
FROM Weeks
LEFT OUTER JOIN  sales ON (Weeks.WeekNum = DATEPART(week, sales.transDate) AND sales.transDate BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate)
GROUP BY Weeks.WeekNum
```

Comment: This works, and is cleaner, but the other query ran faster on my tests. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

As @msmucker0527 wrote get rid of `WHERE (sales.transDate BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate)`.
You can do it also this way:

```
SELECT Weeks.WeekNum, SUM(sales.quantity) AS sales
FROM Weeks W  
     LEFT JOIN sales S ON W.WeekNum = DATEPART(week, S.transDate)
            AND S.transDate BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate)
GROUP BY W.WeekNum
```

Also, this `WHERE (sales.transDate BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate)` guarantee the `Index Scan` of `Sales` table which can greatly slow down your query.
 
You'd better include columns `WeekFirstDate datetime` and `WeekLastDate datetime` into `Weeks` table and `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Name ON Sales (TransDate) INCLUDE (quantity)`. In this case your query can be changed this way:

```
SELECT Weeks.WeekNum, SUM(sales.quantity) AS sales
FROM Weeks W  
     LEFT JOIN sales S ON S.transDate>=W.WeekFirstDate
                          AND S.transDate<=W.WeekLastDate
                          AND S.transDate BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate)
GROUP BY W.WeekNum
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to SQL and I have much to learn about indexes and such things.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Weeks.WeekNum, SUM(sales.quantity) AS sales
FROM Weeks 
LEFT JOIN sales 
       ON Weeks.WeekNum = DATEPART(week, sales.transDate) and
          sales.transDate BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate
WHERE Weeks.WeekNum BETWEEN DATEPART(week, @fromDate) AND 
                            DATEPART(week, @toDate)
GROUP BY Weeks.WeekNum
```

Comment: @CYMR0: In what way did it not work? What was returned by the query?